# Django: get all objects among the foreignkey and inheritance related models?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Belows are my model design:

```
class Exchange(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Symbol(BaseModel):
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ASymbol(Symbol):
    a_property = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class BSymbol(Symbol):
    b_property = models.CharField(max_length=20)


my_exchange = Exchange.objects.first()
```

How can I get all `BSymbol` objects using `my_exchange` variable and related manager? Something like `my_exchange.symbol_set.filter(~~~)`?

**Notice** : `Symbol` is not an abstract class.

Thanks

Comment: you have to add a foreignkey  to the BSymbol class and after that you can use the reverse relationship to access the bsymbol as you described  my_exchange.bsymbol_set.filter()

Comment: @LeLouch Then every time I add new type of `Symbol` class, such as `CSymbol`, do I have to add `foreignkey` field??

Comment: yes everytime you add class you need to add a foreignkey to link em. i think it's easier to make one class Symbol and add all property to it after that you can use a single foreignkey and access any property you want

Comment: @LeLouch But `ASymbol`, `BSymbol` have some different fields as well as common fields. For example, `BSymbol` need two more extra fields which `ASymbol` doesn't need. If I put all these fields in one `Symbol` class, than `ASymbol` would have empty values on these fields, which seems to look inefficient and bad model design?

Comment: not too sure about what is the best practice is in this case is , if you want to make multiple classes you have to add a foreignkey each time .otherwise you have to make one class with a single foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

You can get `BSymbol` objects with `my_exchange` object using the following:

```
BSymbol.objects.filter(exchange=my_exchange)
```

but not with related manager.

Comment: What's wrong with that? Based on your question I would have to agree with unixia.